# Select/Option Value into SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I'm what im trying to accomplish is have a select form element with pre-defined options

```
<select name="select1">
   <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
   <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
   <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

my sql is the following

```
$OptionValue = $_POST['select1'];
```

is that how i should grab the value of the selected option from a form and put it into a php variable to be queried?

Comment: that's about all you'd need. assuming `Value 2` was selected in the form, you'll get `value2` in `$_POST['select1']`

Comment: $OptionValue = $_POST['select1']; is not Mysql it's PHP. Depending how your form is set up and what your looking to do with this from depends on whether you want a POST or GET with PHP

Comment: Is this how I would write it if i wanted what ever option the user selected?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are filtering your user input to prevent against sql injection.  This alone is quite insecure.

Make sure that you are using either PDO or MySQLi. And if not using prepared statements, your user input needs to be escaped.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Essentially you have it right though.

**Edit:**

From the client side I could easily change it to:

```
<select name="select1">
   <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
   <option value="';DROP TABLE users">Value 2</option>
   <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

or similar... and now you're screwed if you haven't escaped your input.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$optionValue = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connection , $_POST['select1'])` before executing the query to prevent the most of SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

First step is prevent SQL injections with prepared statements. Example: [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Use this to put your selected option into query:
    
    `$mySelectedOption = $_POST['select1'];
    $query = "SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name = '{$mySelectedOption}'";`